# How do you hide a UIToolbar?

Tags: ipad, sdk, ios5, xcode4.2

I have 2 buttons within a toolbar. Is there a way to hide the toolbar and still show the 2 buttons? This is what have so far:

```
  UIBarButtonItem *cameraButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                 initWithTitle:@"Camera"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(useCamera:)];
 /*    UIBarButtonItem *cameraRollButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                     initWithTitle:@"Camera Roll"
                                     style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                     target:self
                                     action:@selector(useCameraRoll:)]; */

NSArray *items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: cameraButton,
                 /* cameraRollButton*/ nil];
[toolbar setItems:items animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question's not very specific. You can remove the toolbar from its super view. You can set its opacity zero. You can set its frame off screen. You can animate the latter two.

Comment: Ah. I've not tried. You could try setting the tintColor to [UIColor clearColor]. And iOS 5 added the ability to set a background image. But UIToolbars tend to have gradient and/or border effects and those might end up looking bad.